# Binary Search Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, class, vector, binary-search

I have written a program which should do the following:

> read product item data from an inventory file and add them in a vector
> object. The program will allow user to view, search and order the
> product items. The inventory file should be updated after the order of
> any item.
>
> - For operation #2 (searching) and #3 (ordering), appropriate
>   messages should be displayed for the input of invalid item name, then
>   program should proceed to process next operation

Expected output:

```
>: 2
Enter the item name to search: table
table not found.

>: 2
Enter the item name to search: Microwave
Microwave is in stock.
```

> - For operation #3 (ordering), program should validate the input
>   number of order and make sure there are enough items in the inventory.
>   Otherwise, display error message and skip the ordering –

Expected output:

```
>: 3
Enter the name of the item: Microwave
Enter the nuber of items: 100
Insufficient inventory.

>: 3
Enter the name of the item: Microwave
Enter the nuber of items: 2
Total cost is $300

>: 3
Enter the name of the item: table
table not found.
```

but when I try to search for the name of the item by name using binary search, it doesn't give me the result I want, example:

1.

```
>: 2
Enter the item name to search: Cooking Range
Cooking Range not found.
```

2. 

```
>: 2
Enter the item name to search: Circular Saw
Circular Saw not found.
```

This is the file that contains the data:

itemData.txt

```
1111
Dish Washer
20 550.5
2222
Microwave
75 150
3333
Cooking Range 
50 850
4444
Circular Saw
150 125
```

And this is the definition of the function I tried to implement to search the items by name:

```
int
searchItemByName(vector<Item> items, string searchName)
{
    int low, high, mid;

    low = 0;
    high = items.size() - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;

        if (items[mid].getName() == searchName)
            return (mid);
        else if (items[mid].getName() > searchName)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
    }
    return (-1);
}
```

Here is the entire program (I've also added a clearer and broader "description" of what the program should do with some tests.):

https://github.com/jrchavez07/project_07

Comment: Note: binary search assumes that the array being searched is ordered by the search key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your GitHub project.

I think you have to sort data before binary search.

Current Data in the sample text file list like this:

```
Dish Washer
Microwave
Cooking Range 
Circular Saw
```

And these are not sorted, so you can not use Binary Search.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, I already solved it. Thank you.